# Is it possible to user mangement with Cloud Foundry for non platform users

Tags: authentication, identity, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I would like to ask if I can use the UAA of Cloud Foundry to manage non platform users(**npu**)?

As example, I have a business application and only npu with credentials are allowed to access the rest-api or the website of the application.

So I mean with npu, users which are not working directly on the platform. The npu will only acess custom self developed applications running on cloud foundry as software as service, non api of cloud foundry like the cloud controller.

I'm working with the cloud foundry offer from sap cloud platform, and in one course on open sap(https://open.sap.com/courses/cp1-2 , Unit 5: Securing Cloud Foundry Applications - Part I) they explain that cloud foundry UAA only takes care of platform users like developers and administrators.

So they tell you, that you have to use a specific SAP Cloud Platform Cloud Foundry feature, to do the npu management with cloud foundry.

But is there a possibility to do the npu management with a core feature of cloud foundry, so that I'm not dependent on the SAP Cloud Platform specific cloud foundry features?

Long text, but this is my question.

I'm looking forward for your answers.

Greetings
Maverin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes. The long answer is, it depends on how much control over your CF deployment you have. If you have admin access to the UAA, I'd suggest creating an [Identity Zone](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/version/4.7.1/index.html#identity-zones). If you don't, consider deploying your own UAA into the foundation -- it is, at its core, just a Java app.